# В чём разница между 2-мя следующими записями? А точнее какой тип объектов будет использоваться в 1-ом случае

Tags: java

```
    List list = new ArrayList();
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

В чём разница между 2-мя следующими записями? А точнее какой тип объектов будет использоваться в 1-ом случае.
И почему работаю следующии операции
list.add(3);
list.add("3rsgh");
Ведь ArrayList основан на массиве, а элементы массива не могут быть разного типа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ни в чём. В рантайме вся информация о типах стирается. И все они будут просто `ArrayList`, по сути.

Указание дженерик типа используется только во время компиляции, чтобы вам удобнее было код писать.